# How to get the variable that triggered the if function?

Tags: javascript

So, I'm working on a game, and I want it so that if any of the variables are "NaN" or undefined, `variableThatTriggeredThis` will be set to 0.

I didn't try anything so far, I have no ideas how I can fix it.

```js
if(example == NaN || foo == NaN || bar == NaN) {
    variableThatTriggeredThis = 0;
}
```

I also wanted to ask if there's a way to select every variable in the code, or for example multiple variables, just like var(one, two) == "100".

Comment: Use separate `if`s

Comment: `example = example || 0;` will probably do what you want. Repeat for other variables.

Comment: Warning: `NaN !== NaN`!!!

Comment: ... use [**`isNaN`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) instead.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Better yet, use `Number.isNaN`.

Answer (score 3):

You can check variables directly. `NaN` or `undefined` are valued as false.

Then use **Logical OR ||**

> `expr1 || expr2`     If `expr1` can be converted to true, returns `expr1`; else, returns `expr2`

Example:

```
example = example || 0 ;
foo = foo || 0 ; 
bar = bar || 0 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you could write this. Here's one option using array destructuring:

```js
let a = 10;
let b = 0/0; // NaN
let c; // undefined

const undefinedOrNaNCheck = value => (value === undefined || Number.isNaN(value)) ? 0 : value;
[a, b, c] = [a, b, c].map(undefinedOrNaNCheck);


console.log([a, b, c]);
```

Comment: I recommend using `typeof value==='undefined'` or `value===void 0` as undefined check, because `undefined` is a valid variable name, so it can be shadowed, or overwritten... Good answer, though

Comment: That seems overkill. `undefined`'s been non-writable since ES5.

Comment: That's true, but it can still be used as a variable name, shadowing the global property: `let undefined='Not really undefined...'; console.log(undefined)`

Answer (score 0):

To coerce a variable into a number (defaulting to 0):

`example = isNaN(example) ? 0 : example * 1;`

To process several variables, one approach is to create a parent object:

```
const scores = {};
scores.example = 10;
scores.foo = undefined;
scores.bar = 'not a number';
```

... allowing iteration like this:

```
Object.keys(scores).forEach(function(key) {   
  scores[key] = isNaN(scores[key]) ? 0 : scores[key] * 1;
});
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anandamasri/dxpvr4Lb/1).

If you're supporting an older version of javascript (eg. older browsers) you'll need to use "var" instead of "const" and use a "for" loop instead of the "forEach" loop shown above.

Comment: @Eperou, I provided a working fiddle.  If you're looking for more help please be specific about what didn't work for you.